# C# Excel Interop - How to add a filter button in column header

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

I'm finding some trouble with C# excel interop, and maybe someone can throw me some light about this.

I want to add programatically a filter button at the column header just like this:

[image]

I think it's related with the AutoFilter Method I've found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.autofilter?view=excel-pia), but I can't make it work.

I've tryed to add it to a range like this (and some other similar ways):

```
Excel.Range myRange = SheetActual.Range[SheetActual.Cells[3, 1], SheetActual.Cells[3, 11]];
object result = myrange.AutoFilter(1, Type.Missing, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
```

but i'm not getting any success...  Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when the code is executed. Is there an error? The filter headers do not show? In my tests, the code appears to work by setting the filters on row 3 for columns 1 to 11. You want the headers to start on row 3? Again, what specifically is not working?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @JohnG, I was getting an error while saving, but I found that the excel format was was wrong. I'll post an answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm answering my question for other people future reference. I found my problem was the excel format I was using to save the workbook. Also I found that is posible to create the autofilter without all those parameters, so to create the filter button:

```
Excel.Range myRange = SheetActual.Range[SheetActual.Cells[3, 1], SheetActual.Cells[3, 11]];
object result = myrange.AutoFilter(1);
```

And for saving the file just use:

```
Workbook.SaveAs("TheSavePath", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefaul);
```